# Xtify : When will a Xid be marked as Inactive

Tags: notifications, push, xtify

When does the Xtify mark an Xid as Inactive? I uninstalled an Xtify App but the Xid is still shown in the Xtify console. When I attempt to send a notification to the uninstalled app's Xid, the request is accepted.

Can you please specify all the conditions in which an Xid is marked inactive. Also what is the mechanism used to determine if the Xid is inactive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XID becomes inactive after two things happen:

1. The user uninstalls the app
2. A push notification (APNS or GCM) is sent to the device and is rejected because the app is not installed.

For iOS, the count of inactive XIDs is updated every day at midnight, so you'll have to wait up to 24 hours to see it become inactive. For GCM the count is updated immediately after the push is sent.