# Xtify XID disassociation doesnt work for multiple user per app scenario

Tags: android, ios, xtify

We are using Xtify services for Push notification in our company. And we keep the XID associated with a customer_id.

We dont have a way to find out if the customer has uninstalled the app. Although it seems like Xtify has a way of knowing this reactively when the push notification fails
Ref: [Xtify : When will a Xid be marked as Inactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039754/xtify-when-will-a-xid-be-marked-as-inactive)

So basically Im after a way that can associate something of an XtifyID with a specific app user and be notified by Xtify when that customer logs out of that app on that device so we prune our XID list.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for this:
http://developer.xtify.com/display/APIs/Inactive+XIDs+API

I have a cron job that runs every night, querying their API for XIDs which were deactivated on the previous day; then I mark the devices as inactive in my local database.